# Blockchain shows a confirmed order still "unspent". How do I reclaim Bitcoin thru Coinbase, so I can place order again

Tags: transactions

I placed an order thru Coinbase using Bitcoin to the address the vendor provided at checkout, and the transaction was confirmed.  However, now several days later, the Blockchain shows the Bitcoin "unspent". I never got the confirmation email from the vendor.  If the vendor doesn't spend it, due to a loss of the order or wrong wallet address, will Coinbase refund my Bitcoin, so I can try to place my order again?

Answer (score 1):

When a transaction output is labelled as "unspent" it means that it is still available for spending. Assuming that the transaction output went to your wallet, it means that your wallet still has that unspent available for spending.

Answer (score 0):

Once a transaction is confirmed, it is irreversible. It can only be touched by the recipient, in this case the vendor. You need to contact them.